# При новой итерации данные переписываются, как воспользоваться массивом?

Tags: java, массивы, список, динамические-массивы

Код может хранить данные в теле while только одну итерацию, при повторной итерации данные переписываются.

Каким можно воспользоваться синтаксисом, чтобы данные записывались и при повторной итерации не переписывались, а добавлялись, причем не сложением, а отдельным значением?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static void printList(String[] x, int[] m) {
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "." + x[i] + "," + " цена: " + m[i] + " руб.");
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "Выберите номер товара и колличество для завершения покупки введите - 'end'");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("В нашем магазине Вы можете приобрести следующие товары: ");
        printList(Food.product, Food.prices);
        int productNumber = 0;
        int currentPrices = 0;
        int porductCount = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("end")) break;
            String[] part = input.split(" ");
            productNumber = Integer.parseInt(part[0]); // здесь не понял, как заполнить массив с каждой новой итерацией
            porductCount = Integer.parseInt(part[1]); // после каждой итерации данные в массиве переписываются
            currentPrices = Food.prices[productNumber];
            sum = productNumber + porductCount * currentPrices;
        }


        System.out.println("Наименование товара   Количество  Цена/за.ед  Общая стоимость" + "\n"
                + Food.product[productNumber] + "                  " + porductCount + "           " + currentPrices
                + "          " +  sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял задачу, то Вам следует добавить какой-то вид списка или расширяемого массива. Обычно используют `ArrayList`. Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```java
List<int[]> cart = new ArrayList<>();//декларируем список массивов
System.out.println("В нашем магазине Вы можете приобрести следующие товары: ");
int productNumber;
int currentPrices;
int porductCount;
int sum;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("end")) break;
    String[] part = input.split(" ");
    productNumber = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
    porductCount = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
    currentPrices = Food.prices[productNumber];
    sum = productNumber + porductCount * currentPrices;
    //добавляем товар в список массивов
    cart.add(new int[]{productNumber, porductCount, currentPrices, sum});
}

System.out.println("Наименование товара   Количество  Цена/за.ед  Общая стоимость");
for (int[] ints : cart) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",Food.product[ints[0]], ints[1], ints[2], ints[3]);
}
```

Т.е выбранные товары начинают добавляться в список выбранных товаров, а потом он выводится построчно.
З.Ы. Сами нормально отформатируйте вывод как надо.
З.З.Ы. Советовал бы вам почитать что-то про коллекции java.

Comment: либо хранить объекты (в том же списке) с переопределенным toString методом. "Объект - это экземпляр класса или массив." Но объект более удобный в использовании, если у вас множество элементов разного контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    
    private final static List<Food> foods = Stream.of(
                new Food("Товар 1", 5), 
                new Food("Товар 2", 2), 
                new Food("Товар 3", 7)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            
            System.out.println("В нашем магазине Вы можете приобрести следующие товары: ");
            printList(foods);
            System.out.println("Выберите номер товара и колличество для завершения покупки введите - 'end'");
            
            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
            
            while (true) {
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("end")) break;
                parseOrder(input).ifPresent(order -> orders.add(order));
            }
            
            printList(orders);
            
            int totalCost = orders.stream().mapToInt(Order::getTotalPrice).sum();
            System.out.println("Общпая стоимость покупок: " + totalCost);
        }
        
    }
    
    private static Optional<Order> parseOrder(String input) {
        try {
            String[] part = input.split(" ");
            return Optional.of(new Order(foods.get(Integer.parseInt(part[0].trim()) - 1),
                    Integer.parseInt(part[1].trim())));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    
    private static void printList(List list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((i+1) + "." + list.get(i));
        }        
    }
    
}

class Order{
    
    private final Food food;
    private final int number;
    private final int totalPrice;

    public Order(Food food, int number) {
        this.food = food;
        this.number = number;
        this.totalPrice = food.getPrice()*number;
    }

    public Food getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public int getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return food + ", количество: " + number + ", общая стоимость: " + totalPrice;
    }
    
}

class Food{
    
    private final String product;    
    private final int price;
        
    public Food(String product, int price) {
        this.product = product;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return product + ", цена: " + price + " руб.";
    }
    
}
```

Попробуйте разобраться, не стесняйтесь задавать вопросы